# Json Array data how to pass into Jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating simple sales system in jsp. want to add data in to the database. i don't know retrieve the data to jsp page. this how i pass the data function

var data =  "&items=" + JSON.stringify((items));

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sales_add.jsp",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data,
```

data passing successfully i check through console.

String[] json =request.getParameterValues("items"); this how i retrive the data to jsp page

```
 for(int x = 0; x < json.length; x++)
        {
       String   item = json[x][0]);
       String  price = json[x][1]);
       String   qty = json[x][2]);
       String  $total = json[x][3]);
```

this code it is not working

Full Code

All sales should be added this table data. i am going to send in to sales_add.jsp page . i checked like this console.log(JSON.stringify(items)); full code i write below.

```
function add_product_to_array(item, price,qty, tot)
{
    var item = [item, price,qty, tot];
    items.push(item);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Table i checked through Console.log it display successfully like this

```
**[["Chocolate",32,"1",32]]
(index):237 [["Chocolate",32,"1",32],["Mango",10,"1",10]]**
```

i sending this way **var data =  "&items=" + JSON.stringify((items)) to sales.add.php page

```
function addProject()
{
    var data = "&items=" + JSON.stringify((items));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sales_add.jsp",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(_data);

            alert("Success");
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: can you post sample value of "data"?

Comment: Table i checked through Console.log it display successfully like this

**[["Chocolate",32,"1",32]]
(index):237 [["Chocolate",32,"1",32],["Mango",10,"1",10]]**

Comment: how to retieve it in jsp sir

Comment: Assumed **items = [["Chocolate",32,"1",32],["Mango",10,"1",10]]**, if so, it fails because you are iterating a stringified array

Comment: so how to do this sir. i am tring this 2 weeks of time i edited the code above sir full code

Comment: Looks an awful lot like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58696929/received-json-data-how-to-pass-in-to-variable-jsp-page ..... please DO NOT repost the same question over and over again !