# Received json data how to pass in to variable Jsp Page

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating a simple sales system in jsp. I want to add data in to the database. I don't know how to retrieve the data into the jsp page. This how I pass the data function:

```
var data = "&items=" + JSON.stringify((items));

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sales_add.jsp",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: data,
```

Data is passing successfully - I checked through console.

This how I retrieve the data on the jsp page:

```
String[] json =request.getParameterValues("items"); 

for(int x = 0; x < json.length; x++)
{
    String item = json[x][0]);
    String price = json[x][1]);
    String qty = json[x][2]);
    String $total = json[x][3]);
}
```

This code it is not working

All sales should be added this table data. I am going to send in to `sales_add.jsp` page. I checked like this

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```

This is my full code:

```
function add_product_to_array(item, price,qty, tot)
{
    var item = [item, price,qty, tot];
    items.push(item);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Table I checked through Console.log it display successfully like this

**[["Chocolate",32,"1",32]]
(index):237 [["Chocolate",32,"1",32],["Mango",10,"1",10]]**
i sending this way **var data = "&items=" + JSON.stringify((items)) to sales.add.jsp page

```
function addProject()
{
    var data = "&items=" + JSON.stringify((items));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sales_add.jsp",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(_data);

            alert("Success");
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);

        }

    });
}
```

I edited Jsp page like this:

```
String jsonData = request.getParameter("data");
```

this format sir

[{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"}]

```
 Connection con1;
PreparedStatement insert;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");   
   con1=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/icepos","root","");        

 for(int x = 0; x < jsonData .length; x++)
        {

              String query = "INSERT INTO sale_product(item,price,qty,total) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

            String   item = jsonData [x]['item']);
            String  price = jsonData [x]['price']);
            String   qty = jsonData [x]['qty']);
            String  total = jsonData [x]['total']);


        }
```

but not working this sir

Answer (score 0):

```
//below in HTML part
<input type="hidden" value='<%=request.getAttribute("items") %>' id='items' name='items'>

//below in js part
<script>
let jsonItems=docuement.querySelector('items').value;//now jsonItems item //carry the recived data , using these js function to reFormat the data 
//JSON.stringify() or JSON.parse() based on what you want to do
<script>
```

Comment: JSON.stringify()  sir

Comment: JSON.stringify(jsonItems) ; // if you want to handeling the JSON object as a string

Comment: what is the type of received data? array or JSON?

Comment: sir i edited above sir what format data displyed in jsp page

Comment: I saw that so if you received the data in JSP successfully what is the exact problem? you assign the received data into hidden input like the answer

Comment: i want add this data into the database.how pass this data using loop sir like string item =

Comment: i edited above sir.i want to add the data in to the database

Comment: jsonData.forEach(function(item,index){ let newJsonData={}; newJsonData.items+=item;  }); //this code will put them as a JSON object like below comment

Comment: {"items":{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"},{"item":"Chocolate","price":"Chocolate","pro_price":"32","qty":"1","total":"32"} }

Comment: $('#tbl-item tbody tr').each(function (row, tr)
    {
        var sub = {
            'item': $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'price': $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').text(),
            'pro_price': $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text(),
            'qty': $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text(),
            'total': $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').text(),
           
        };
        table_data.push(sub);
    });
    
    var data1 =  JSON.stringify(table_data);

Comment: then put the result in JSON.stringify(newJsonData);// will convert it to string and you can send it by AJAX as a string then using library such as GSON you serialize the string JSON object in the servlet

Comment: can you write the code in it big help for me GSON  i download the jar and add it too

Comment: you want to add the result into an HTML table or DataBase table?

Comment: database table sir

Comment: in the above code, you look like extract the items from HTML table!

Comment: sample GSON code : List<Services> service=new ArrayList<Services>();
   AdminDao admindao=new AdminDao();
   service=admindao.getUsersData();
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(service, new TypeToken<List<Services>>() {}.getType());
   JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
   
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size();i++) {
   System.out.println("========>"+jsonArray.get(i));
   }
   resp.setContentType("application/json");
   resp.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

Comment: you need to understand the sample GSON code then apply it on your scenario